# Run a function multiple times with different arguments for each run

Tags: python, list, function, loops, arguments

I have a function that I want to run several times with a different argument for each successive run. I am not sure how to go about this. I have created a list of the values I want.

```
> for x in list:
>     print(x)
> 
> list = ["2", "5", "10"]
> 
> for y in list1:
>     print(y)
> 
> list1 = ["2", "5", "10"]
```

I want to pass the list to a function that I have.

```
> Def function(x,y):
   z = x*y   
> return z 
> result = function(x,y)
```

Could I simply define the arguments as the names of my lists?

I think I am missing another loop.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `zip()` builtin.  btw what do you want to do with the result each time?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, you're overwriting the built-in name.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. The first code snippet shows you doing exactly what youo ask -- you're calling the `print()` function multiple times with a different argument each time. Why do you think it would be different for your own function?

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(x, y):
    return x*y
Xs = [2, 5, 10]
Ys = [2, 5, 10]
result = [function(x,y) for x, y in zip(Xs, Ys)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I *think* you may be trying to do...

You have two lists. Each list is comprised of strings which represent integer values. You want to multiply corresponding elements from each of the lists and produce an output.

```
list1 = ['10', '20', '30']
list2 = ['5', '6', '7']

def function(x, y):
    return int(x) * int(y)

print(*map(function, list1, list2), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
50
120
210
```

Comment: `zip` is redundant with `map`, see doc of `map` for the signature with more parameters

Comment: @cards Not really redundant because I was passing a tuple which was unpacked in *function()*. But you're right, it was unnecessary so I've simplified the code

Comment: FYI, `itertools.starmap` handles that use case. `starmap(f, lst)` is the same as `map(lambda x: f(*x), lst)`. But yes, `map(f, x, y)` is simpler than `starmap(f, zip(x, y))`. :)